# Can't read values that are outside of function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am learning JavaScript and AngularJS.  I want to use the values that are outside of function, but I don't know how to access them.

Here is my code (AngularJS Controller):

```
var init = function() {
    $http.get('getSomeValues').then(function (res) {
        var returnArray = res.data; // Result is array

        for(var i=0; i < returnArray.length; i++) { // Loop through the array
            console.log("THIS WORKS FINE: ", returnArray[i].value); // It works
            $http.get('getOtherValues/' + returnArray[i].value).then(function (res) {
                console.log("WHAT'S IN IT: ", returnArray[i].value); // Shows 'undefined' error
            });
        }
    });
};
init();
```

So basically I want to access the array *returnArray*, but I can't.  Is there any good way to access the values?  I assume that *'.then(function ..'* causes error..

Comment: Read about JavaScipt Closures. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Comment: You can use res. If you need what you sent in returnArray[i], you can repost it back in res by modifying getOtherValues code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use a [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/):

Replace:

```
for(var i=0; i < returnArray.length; i++) { // Loop through the array
    $http.get('getOtherValues/' + returnArray[i].value).then(function (res) {
        console.log("WHAT'S IN IT: ", returnArray[i].value); // Shows 'undefined' error
    });
}
```

With:

```
for(var i=0; i < returnArray.length; i++) { // Loop through the array
    (function(data){
        $http.get('getOtherValues/' + data.value).then(function (res) {
            console.log("WHAT'S IN IT: ", data.value); // Shows 'undefined' error
        });
    }(returnArray[i]))
}
```

This ensures that, for the current iteration of the `for` loop, the `data` variable will be set to the current `raturnArray` item.

Comment: this is elegant answer

Comment: @Cerbrus Oh I mean that could you explain the error from my original code

Comment: The problem was that the loop continued before the `get` could finish. That caused `i` to be something it shouldn't have been, in the `returnArray[i]`'s. In case this answer provided the solution for you, could you consider accepting my answer, please?